# Sum based on two columns from another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've got this table named "A" and I want to fill the Sales SUM column with the sum of sales from another table group by date and country. The other table is named "B" and got also Date, Country and Sales columns however the number of dates and countries differ. I don't want to join this tables I would like to achieve this in DAX. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with DAX and virtual relationship:

```
SumSales = calculate( sum('B'[Sales])
, TREATAS(SUMMARIZE('A','A'[Date],'A'[Country]), 'B'[Date],'B'[Country])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't work at first because I added it as a new column. It works as a measure.